# How can I bypass the login screen during checkout in Commerce 2?

Tags: commerce

I'm building a site where I want to allow guests to purchase without creating a user account. This appears to be default behaviour in Commerce 2.1 (the message stating that the user can create an account at the end of checkout is currently not implemented although I know work is being done on that in this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2857157).

However, I also don't want to offer guests the option to log in, which is what currently happens.

So, I want to simply bypass the Login page and go straight to the checkout page.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem by editing the Default checkout flow at /admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows, where I could simply disable the **Login or continue as guest** step.

Comment: When i try to implement this solution it does not work because the "recap" step doesn't contain the filled in fields anymore..

Comment: It looks like this is a change in Commerce 8.x-2.4. I tried it as an anonymous user and, as you described, my address details did not appear in the Stripe credit card section on the Review screen (the address details do appear when I'm logged in). However, I was able to continue and complete the transaction (a real transaction, not a test) so it looks like the details are being stored and sent to the payment provider, they're just not being displayed on the review screen. I'll raise it as an issue in the Commerce queue.

Comment: You're right, upgrading to 2.4 fixed this.