# Skip Guest checkout step - go straight to checkout form

Tags: 8, commerce

Is it possible that when you click on "Checkout" in the shopping cart view you go straight to Guest Checkout?

In this case you skip the "login as existing customer" or "checkout as guest" step.

Using DrupalCommerce 2 for Drupal 8.

I tried [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250049/how-can-i-bypass-the-login-screen-during-checkout-in-commerce-2) but it didnt work for me because on the "Review" step the filled-in fields are not being displayed.

Comment: The solution you linked to is the right one, this question is a duplicate.

If you're encountering a bug at the Review step, open a bug report in the Commerce queue.

Comment: Nevermind, bug was fixed in commerce 2.4